# How to create Table Layout of same size column

Tags: android-layout

I am new to android. I want to create a layout,
Having **Linear layout -->** consist of **two text view-->** than **table view.**
**Table view --> two columns** having **equal size**.
**1**st column having **huge data***. so it should be **word wrap and scroll vertically**.
**2*nd column contains a **image**.

How can i do it. As **i tried** but i am **not** able to create **2 columns of equal size**, 1st having vertical scroll bar...

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property as :

```
android:streachColumn="*";
```

And

```
android:weight="*";
```

Property. This will help you.